# itemindex error in searchlookupedit or lookupedit

Tags: c#

I want to get the information of the item selected in lookupedit or searchlookupedit, but the item index keeps appearing as 0, so I only get the information of the first item.

```
SearchLookUpEdit view = sender as SearchLookUpEdit; 
if (view != null)
{    
   DataRowView dvRow = view.GetSelectedDataRow() as DataRowView; 
}
```

Comment: You have to see you the index of the search word

Comment: I want the row of items selected in lookupedit, not gridview.